# Loop for imputation

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, imputation

I make an imutation for a single variable & return it to the same variable

```
X = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['a'])
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=0)
X = imp.fit_transform(X)
df['a'] = X
```

However I have many variables & want to use loop like this

```
f = df[[a, b, c, d, e]]
for k in f:
    X = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=k)
    imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=0)
    X = imp.fit_transform(X)
    df.k = X
```

but:

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'a' was passed
```

How can I use loop for imputation & return variables in dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataFrame iterates over it's columns names so k == 'a' in this instance rather than the first column. You could implement it with

```
f = df[[a, b, c, d, e]]
for k in f:
    X = df[k]
    imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=0)
    X = imp.fit_transform(X)
    df[k] = X
```

But you probably just want to build a new dataframe using apply column wise. Something like

```
df = df.apply(imp.fit_transform, raw=True, broadcast=True)
```

or pandas has it's own methods for working with missing data: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#filling-with-a-pandasobject

Answer (score 1):

```
for k in f:
    X = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[k])
    imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=0)
    X = imp.fit_transform(X)
    df[k] = X
```